# Saving Mongoose Document which has selected fields removed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Does a `.save()` on a mongoose document which is retrieved from a query which has `.select()`ed fields removed cause an incomplete document to be written over the document's representation in mongo?

If so, does that mean that I will have to either not use field selection or issue a `.update()` separately?

e.g.

```
Posts
  .findById(someId)
  .select('-body')
  .exec(function(err, post){
    post.edited = Date.now();
    post.save(function(err){
      // will `post` still have the body field if I query for it from the database again?
    })
  })
```

Comment: I just ran into a (bug? issue?) with 4.1.6 where when I select("_id") and then immediately save() I see data loss randomly across a large document.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, just try :)

```
// uses streamline.js
var mongoose  = require('mongoose');
var client    = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var Doc = mongoose.model('Doc', new mongoose.Schema({
  name  : String,
  body  : String
}));

var doc     = new Doc({ name : 'foo', body : 'this is the body' }).save(_);
var result  = Doc.findById(doc._id).select('-body').exec(_);

console.log('R#1', result);

doc.name    = 'new name';
var newdoc  = doc.save(_);

var result2 = Doc.findById(newdoc._id).exec(_);

console.log('R#2', result2);
```

This prints:

```
R#1 { name: 'foo', _id: 525506fb23c4904b61000001, __v: 0 }
R#2 { __v: 0,
  _id: 525506fb23c4904b61000001,
  body: 'this is the body',
  name: 'new name' }
```

So the `body` property still exists.

The reason why is that `.save()` for an existing document actually executes an `.update()` internally.